# applying multiple summary statstics on a particular column of data frame

Tags: python

I want to apply multiple statistics functions like mean, median, variance etc. on a particular column of a data frame. I used following code. It produced results but not in required manner.  Please tell me how i can write such kind of functions.

```
def summary(x):
    output1=x["Close"].mean
    output2=x["Close"].median
    output=(output1,output2)
    return output
summary(infy)
required_output=(mean,median)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.Close.agg(["mean", "median"])
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is missing braces. Apply this chunk of code.

```
def summary(x):
    output1=x["Close"].mean()
    output2=x["Close"].median()
    output=(output1,output2)
    return output
summary(infy)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to *call* the mean and median methods:

```
x["Close"].mean()   # Note the brackets
x["Close"].median()
```

But as others have stated, pandas has a nice built-in `agg` for this task.